# Resetting a Jquery plugin on-click

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, logic

I have tied this jQuery Bar Graph plugin with a function that I created.

My code is on fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/swordfish0321/9Rkc2/3/

Problem:
If the 'Calculate' button is clicked more that once it stacks text on top of itself rendering the graph non-useable. I tried inserting a reset button that successfully resets the form data and attempts to reset the bar graph, but really just performs a show and hide and the problem persists.

Question:
Anyone have any ideas of how I could either reset this calculator without a page refresh and/or incorporate the reset functionality into the 'Calculate" button after it's fired once?

Cheers.

Comment: Look at the DOM to see what's changing.

Comment: I cleaned your fiddle a little. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Rkc2/9/)

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't feel like tunneling through Code Mountain.  However, every single time the "calculate" button is clicked why not do a "reset" first, then calculate?  Edit: Oh, ok, that's what you're asking how to do.  I don't know... you wrote it, just run through the reset function before the calculation function... why is this a problem?

Comment: @Sparky672 "I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't feel like tunneling through Code Mountain" got a legit lol out of me, thanks for your input mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to run `.reset()` on a DIV element. This will only work for forms.

What you want todo is really just remove the charts when a user clicks reset. You can do this like: `$('#chart').empty();`